# ListBoxFor in .NET Core not binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I cannot get this ListBox to have a value. It worked in MVC4.5, from which I am translating; cannot get to work in MVC Core. Swear it was working at some point; now it is not.

Have tried:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19144613/2496266
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40308906/2496266
etc.

View

```
        <div class="tb-field desc-field">
            @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.workerRequests,
                new SelectList(ViewBag.workerRequests, "Value", "Text"),
                    new { id = "workerRequests2_WO-"+ Model.ID, tabindex = "22", style="min-width: 16em;"}
            )
        </div>
```

Controller (GET)

```
            wo.workerRequests = new List<ViewModel.WorkerRequest>();
            ViewData["workerRequests"] = new SelectList(wo.workerRequests);
            return PartialView("Create", wo);
```

Controller (POST)

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create(WorkOrder wo, string userName)
        {
            ModelState.ThrowIfInvalid();
            var modelUpdated = await _adaptor.TryUpdateModelAsync(this, wo);
            // ... "wo.WorkerRequests" is empty here ^
        }
```

Entity

```
        public virtual ICollection<WorkerRequest> workerRequests { get; set; }
```

Additional info:

Apparently it is coming across in the Request, but as a StringValue:

[image: StringValue_in_request]

...apparently all of them are string values. It's not getting bound to its desired type.

Basically:

1. It has getters and setters on the entity.
2. I'm populating the ViewData before serving the page.
3. I'm using a SelectList(arg) where arg is of type myModel.myProperty.

We are selecting the Worker in the WorkerRequest from the database (nested type). Is this due to the lazy-loading bugs? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are creating 2 `SelectList` objects for the view.

Once in controller:

```
ViewData["workerRequests"] = new SelectList(wo.workerRequests);
```

And again in the view:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.workerRequests,
    new SelectList(ViewBag.workerRequests, "Value", "Text"),
```

You only need to create one and the best place would be in the view. So change your controller code to populate the `ViewData` with the data and let the view create the `SelectList` to display:

```
ViewData["workerRequests"] = wo.workerRequests;
```

Now you should see the list box populated with the data.

Comment: Unfortunately, at least in `Create()`, that does not seem to do it. Trying it in `Edit` just to be sure.

Comment: In the end this had nothing to do with the ViewData and everything to do with the object being sent in the request; it wouldn't pull workerRequests out of the WorkOrder no matter how I did the SelectList. Nevertheless accepting this as answer because it is the correct way to make the list.

Answer (score 0):

For the curious, [this](https://github.com/SavageLearning/Machete/blob/master/Machete.Web/Controllers/WorkOrderController.cs#L203) is what we ended up with:

#### Controller

```
        public ActionResult Create(Domain.WorkOrder wo, string userName, List<Domain.WorkerRequest> workerRequestList)
        {
            UpdateModel(wo);
            Domain.WorkOrder neworder = woServ.Create(wo, userName);           

            // JSON object with new work order data
            var result = map.Map<Domain.WorkOrder, ViewModel.WorkOrder>(neworder);
            return Json(new 
            {
                sNewRef = result.tabref,
                sNewLabel = result.tablabel,
                iNewID = result.ID
            }, 
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

#### [View](https://github.com/SavageLearning/Machete/blob/master/Machete.Web/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/WorkOrder.cshtml#L85)

```
        <div class="tb-label desc-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.workerRequests)
            <br />
            <input type="button" value="@Machete.Web.Resources.WorkOrder.requestAdd" class="formButton" id="addRequestBtn-@(Model.ID)"/>
            <input type="button" value="@Machete.Web.Resources.WorkOrder.requestRemove" class="formButton" id="removeRequestBtn-@(Model.ID)"/>
        </div>
        <div class="tb-field desc-field">
            @Html.ListBox("workerRequests2", new SelectList(ViewBag.workerRequests, "Value", "Text"), new { id = "workerRequests2_WO-"+ Model.ID, tabindex = "22", style="min-width: 16em;"})
        </div>
```